# how to check if a number is present a JSON string?

Tags: java, json, search, jackson

I have one number called , chNumber like below

"1499094567"

and their are are 100 thousands , for example 110000 , json strings , is their any most efficient way to check whether this number completely whole , present those 110000 json strings ?

I tried with Java String contains method and it is running in good time , but problem which is serious is , for example if one JSON string contains the number "8981499094567123" , if you see this number has the above number so contains method is returning true , but it should not , we want to return JSONs , which contains that target number as whole , and complete ,

and i tried using jackson lib and but it is taking too much hell lot of time with String contains my work used complete with max 15 to 20 min , but with Jackson it is taking more than 1 hr , so can any one suggest how to do this search .

***Note : like that i have nearly 500 to 600 target numbers , to search in 110000 JSON strings every time***

I used Regex also , it also taking too much time

Comment: Maybe you can try do some regex if you know the format of the JSON (though regex can take very long too). Also you can try search for `: 1499094567,` instead of `1499094567`, note the extra colon and the comma after it, assuming it is a value

Comment: I tried regex with java mattern patching , still it is taking very long time

Comment: Yea... regex will take long. Try the second method I mentioned above.

Comment: the number is in double quotes inside the json , so 1499094567,  it will not work , because before comma we need one double quote like for example
"chNumber": "1499094567",    this is the format , in this case "1499094567\","   is this fine to search or someother string i need frame ?

Comment: You should be able to search for `\"1499094567\"` right? Or even better, search the entire string of `\"chNumber\": \"1499094567\"`. The longer the target string is, the faster the search is by using the Boyer–Moore string-search algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Combine both approaches:

1. Find all JSON files containing substring. I guess their number << number of all files
2. For this found subset use Jackson to filter only those files which actually contain the desired value, by filtering garbage like `8981499094567123`